# Why don't things like `Math` and `JSON` return their keys? What's special about them?

Tags: javascript

Things like `Math` and `JSON` are somehow objects *with keys*, but they report as having no keys.

```
> Object.keys(JSON);
Array(0) []

> [...JSON]
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

> Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(JSON);
Array(1) [Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]
  length:1
  __proto__:Array(0) [, …]
  0: Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
```

My best guess is they've been designed to be non-iterable. But why? And how?

Comment: [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(JSON)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). See [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). Read the documentation about [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols).

Comment: Damn, I could have sworn I had tried that. Guess this one is pretty open-and-shut.